# How to remove redundant data from SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi: I'm pulling data from a table that has a main id code linked to a user, but each time the user changes his/her name, an extra record is added. I'm trying to pull a list of current users and any old names they might have used in the past. I'm using an outer join to pick up at least one former name and one extra former name.

Here's the query:

```
select
PrimaryName.PM_PDM,
PrimaryName.PM_ID,
PrimaryName.PM_AltID,
PrimaryName.PM_Change,
PrimaryName.PM_FName,
PrimaryName.PM_LName,
OldNames1.ON_PDM,
OldNames1.ON_Change,
OldNames1.ON_ID,
OldNames1.ON_AltID,
OldNames1.ON_FName,
OldNames1.ON_LName,
OldNames2.O2_PDM,
OldNames2.O2_Change,
OldNames2.O2_ID,
OldNames2.O2_AltID,
OldNames2.O2_FName,
OldNames2.O2_LName

from
(select
S_PDM as PM_PDM,
S_ID as PM_ID,
S_FIRST_NAME as PM_FName,
S_LAST_NAME as PM_LName,
S_CHANGE_IND as PM_Change,
S_SURROGATE_ID as PM_AltID
from S
WHERE S_CHANGE_IND is null) PrimaryName,

(select
S_PDM as ON_PDM,
S_ID  as ON_ID,
S_FIRST_NAME as ON_FName,
S_LAST_NAME as ON_LName,
S_CHANGE_IND as ON_Change,
S_SURROGATE_ID as ON_AltID
from S
where S_CHANGE_IND = 'N') OldNames1,

(select
S_PDM as O2_PDM,
S_ID  as O2_ID,
S_FIRST_NAME as O2_FName,
S_LAST_NAME as O2_LName,
S_CHANGE_IND as O2_Change,
S_SURROGATE_ID as O2_AltID
from S
where S_CHANGE_IND = 'N') OldNames2


where (OldNames1.ON_PDM = PrimaryName.pm_pdm)
and
  (OldNames1.ON_PDM = OldNames2.O2_PDM (+)
   and
   OldNames1.ON_AltID <> OldNames2.O2_AltID (+))

order by 2
```

here is a sample of my result:

```
PM_PDM  |PM_ID  |PM_ID2 |PM_CHANGE  |PM_FNAME   |PM_LNAME   |ON_PDM |ON_CHANGE  |ON_ID  |ON_ID2 |ON_FNAME   |ON_LNAME   |O2_PDM     |O2_CHANGE  |O2_ID2 |O2_ID  |O2_FNAME   |O2_LNAME
1111    |2222   |3333   |           |Betty      |Boop       |1111   |N          |2222   |4444   |Betty      |Smith      |1111       |N          |5555   |2222   |Betty      |Jones
1111    |2222   |3333   |           |Betty      |Boop       |1111   |N          |2222   |5555   |Betty      |Jones      |1111       |N          |4444   |2222   |Betty      |Smith
```

I just one line returned for the three names:

1. Betty Boop 2.Betty Smith 3. Betty Jones

Right now, it's returning

1. Betty Boop 2.Betty Smith 3.Betty Jones
2. Betty Boop 2.Betty Jones 3.Betty Smith

I know it's the last join, but I'm not sure how to limit it to only one line. The query is working the way it's supposed to, but I need to edit it to only return one line.

Comment: Fix your joins to use modern JOIN syntax, instead of the ancient obsolete A,B join syntax. That should make the error clearer and easier to spot.

Comment: Could you also explain the problem. I see you've explained what you've done and shown result data but I can't see any question nor problem with the results.

Comment: I'm trying to limit the result to one line per user: Current User Name, First Previous User Name, Second Previous User Name. Right now, the joins are picking up User Name, First User Name and Second User Name. It's also returning the second line of User Name, Second User Name and First User Name. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Lyndey What are you expecting the results to look like? Please update your question to include what you want to see.

Comment: @Boneist: I edited the question. Further explanations are at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: @Lyndey Right, but your query is returning lots of columns, yet your expected output only has the first and last names, presumably comma separated. Is that what you want? Just the names in a delimited list?

Comment: @Boneist : I was just trying to be brief. In the table I put up, all I want is the first line to be returned, not the second.

Comment: Equal brevity in the original query and its output would have been welcome :)

Comment: @Lyndey what do you want to have happen if there are have been more than 2 name changes? Currently, you'd have some duplications, if all you're after is the list of names - you can see this by running `WITH sd AS (SELECT LEVEL ID FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4) SELECT * FROM sd INNER JOIN sd sd2 ON sd.id < sd2.id;` - you can see that each id appears 3 times in the results.

Comment: @boniest very few records in the database have more than two name changes, but it is a good question. I would like it to have the primary name and the names with alt_Id's in descending order. If I can update it to one line, great, but if it takes multiple lines, I can live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign numbers to each change using `row_number()` and join these data twice using only rows where `RN = 1` and `RN = 2`:

```
with c as (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by pdm order by id desc) rn
             from s where chg = 'N')
select s.pdm, s.id, s.name, c1.id id1, c1.name name1, c2.id id2, c2.name name2
  from (select * from s where chg is null) s
  left join c c1 on c1.pdm = s.pdm and c1.rn = 1
  left join c c2 on c2.pdm = s.pdm and c2.rn = 2
```

---

Test:

```
with s(pdm, id, chg, name) as (select 1, 1, 'N',  'Smith' from dual union all
                               select 1, 2, 'N',  'Jones' from dual union all
                               select 1, 3, null, 'Brown' from dual),
     c as (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by pdm order by id desc) rn
             from s where chg = 'N')
select s.pdm, s.id, s.name, c1.id id1, c1.name name1, c2.id id2, c2.name name2
  from      (select * from s where chg is null) s
  left join c c1 on c1.pdm = s.pdm and c1.rn = 1
  left join c c2 on c2.pdm = s.pdm and c2.rn = 2


PDM  ID   NAME    ID1  NAME1   ID2  NAME2
---  ---  ------  ---  ------  ---  ------
  1    3  Brown     2  Jones     1  Smith
```

Comment: This answer is a good start. I still have to work through getting things on one row, but It is getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last join condition to this:

```
 OldNames1.ON_AltID < OldNames2.O2_AltID (+)
```

Explanation: you have two `AltID` values `4444` and `5555`. `4444 <> 5555` is true and so is  `5555 <> 4444`. Hence your existing condition ....

```
 OldNames1.ON_AltID <> OldNames2.O2_AltID (+)
```

.... produces a cross join and so you get two records. Changing the condition to join on less than eliminates the cross join because `5555 < 4444` is false.

Comment: Outer join, so that will still produce 2 rows: 1111-4444-5555 and 1111-5555-null.